# Вставка видео из YouTube на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, php

Как сделать, что-бы на сайте было так, как это реализовано в ВК, то есть в ВК ты жмешь на картинку, как впрочем и в Ютубе, а потом появляется плеер, а когда вставляешь видео, то получается, без картинки сразу плеер.
И где взять картинку которая обрамляет плеер?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При клике на картинку, рисуете и показываете DIV внутри которого находится IFRAME который даёт ю-тьб. Ну что-то вида:

```
 <iframe width="700" height="420" class="ifvideo" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XXXXXXXXXXX?color=white&theme=light" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Проявление блока и анимацию оставляем вам.

Картинка-превью лежит по адресу `http://img.youtube.com/vi/XXXXXXXXXXX/0.jpg`
Где ХХХХХХ - та же последовательность символов, что и в видео.